# Finding the Eigenvectors from a matrix

Tags: c#, matrix

I am trying to make an AHP program using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18GWVtVAAzs&feature=youtu.be) (4:50). I am stuck at finding the Eigenvectors for the criteria weights. I used a class library from [this webpage](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.csharp.html#unit_evd) but the results differ a lot.

This is the testcode I wrote so far.

```
private void button_calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double[,] matrix = new double[,]
        {
            {1, 1/3, 1/2},  
            {3, 1, 1 },
            {2, 1, 1}
        };
        double[] eigenValue;
        double[,] eigenVector;


        alglib.smatrixevd(matrix, 3, 1, false, out eigenValue, out eigenVector);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a third party library you should always read very carefully the provided documentation.

In the case of `smatrixevd` it clearly states:

> A: **symmetric** matrix which is given by its upper or lower triangular part...

Bolded part for emphasis.

Your input matrix is not symetric, so there you go.

The function you want to call for a general matrix is [`rmatrixevd`](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.csharp.html#sub_rmatrixevd)

Comment: I see. I have to admit that I thought even matrixes  have just the same number of rows and columns... I'll look that up, and thank you.

Comment: @user3699148 it has nothing to do with rows and columns; you can only evaluate eigenvalues of a square matrix to begin with. A symmetric matrix means that given a matrix `A`, it's transposed matrix is the same; `transpose(A) = A`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to  include all 11  .cs library files present in alglib to get the result of eigen value and eigen vector becoz one .cs file is dependent on other .cs file. Mind it!!!!!!!!!!!

cs file are as follows:

```
alglibmisc.cs - contains different algorithms which are hard to classify
dataanalysis.cs - contains data mining algorithms
diffequations.cs - contains differential equation solvers
fasttransforms.cs - contains FFT and other related algorithms
integration.cs - contains numerical integration algorithms
interpolation.cs - contains interpolation algorithms
linalg.cs - contains linear algebra algorithms
optimization.cs - contains optimization algorithms
solvers.cs - contains linear and nonlinear solvers
specialfunctions.cs - contains special functions
statistics.cs - statistics
alglibinternal.cs - contains internal functions which are used by other packages, but not exposed to the external world
ap.cs - contains publicly accessible vector/matrix classes, most important and general functions and other "basic" functionality.
```

TO get more information look this: [Manual of alglib](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.csharp.html)

For eigenvector and eigenvalue look this:[How to use eigen vector library](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.csharp.html#struct_eigsubspacereport)

I have tried this and it will work...